# Online or "forward only" scaling in python (skicit-learn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, signal-processing

I'm working with EEG time series in Python. I use standardscaler from sklearn.preprocessing to scale my series for mean 0 and std 1, but it gives me just to options of transforming my series:

-fit_transform: first calculates mean and std looking on whole series and then transforms it

-transform: transforms series knowing mean and std from some other series on which I used 'fit' before

I wonder if there is some method in skicit learn for "online" scaling, where it would scale each timepoint looking just on previous timepoints of the same series. It would be beneficial for some applications, like BCI, where you can't look on the future data.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. You can just call `fit_transform` on a slice of your Series (the previous timepoints) and then apply transform as data roll in, but maybe I'm missing the point completely.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it is either computationaly expensive, or not optimal. It is easy to take a slice of, lets say, first 10%, then compute parameters and transform rest of the series. What I would like to do is kind of "adaptive" scaling, so in every point i use a slice of all previous points. Slicing and fitting transform every point (or even every 10,100 or 1000 points) could take a long time. I was just asking if there is some default method to do this in sklearn, which would be optimalized.

Comment: You can use train test split to take a random sample of data. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)